# Outlook "right click on contact" modifing

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to write Outlook 2010 add-in using Visual Studio 2013.

How can I modify the menu that is opened after I'm right-clicking a "contact card" in the Contacts page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on CodeProject could help [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627848/Adding-Custom-Menus-to-Outlook-Contacts)

Right click on the solution explorer, and add New Ribbon (XML) Item. Replace Generated XML with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
      <contextMenus> 
        <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuContactItem"> 
          <menuSeparator id="mniMailItemMenuSeparator" />
          <button id="customButton"
                  label="Name of your Menu Item"   insertBeforeQ="Copy"
                  getImage="LoadCustomImage"
                  onAction="OnMyButtonClick" /> 
        </contextMenu>
      </contextMenus>
  </customUI>
```

Now you just need to add the

```
OnMyButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
```

to your Ribbon1.cs code behind.

Comment: And to add:
`protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new Ribbon1();
        }`
To the `ThisAddIn` class